# Using JS variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 function  lookup ( inputString )
 {
     var responseArray = new Array();
     // alert(inputString);
     $.post("/airmanage/networkadmin/partnership_management/getMainDist.jsp",user: ""+inputString+""},
     function(data){
     // alert(data);
     responseArray = data.split(",");
     //alert(responseArray.length);
     });
     return responseArray;
     }

        var x   =   new  Array();
        x    =   lookup("a");
        alert (  x   );
```

I'm a newbie in jquery so can you guys help me out.
The responseArray comes empty when I place the alert.

I am not able to use the variable responseArray defined in js function to be assigned to a data in jquery function, please let me know how to use this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronus, there for it doesnt make sense to call a function and expect it to return the results of the ajax call. There is alot more wrong with your code but even if you fixed it you would have that issue. What you need to do is ether have you lookup function accept a callback or execute all your code directly in the callback to `$.post`.

Making lookup async with its own callback:

```
function lookup(inputString, callback){
   $.post(
     "/airmanage/networkadmin/partnership_management/getMainDist.jsp", 
     {"user": inputSting},
     function(data) {
        if(typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}


// usage
lookup('theInputStringValue', function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

The main reason to do it that way would just be to consolidate the URL and parameter encoding for all "lookups" and make it easier to use instead of repeatedly using `$.post` for the exact same call in numerous spots. Beyond that you arent doing anything special here you couldnt do directly in the callback supplied to `$.post`.

Comment: Thank you for the early reply, actually i am able to get the data in the callback which comes as a string seperated by ',' I am converting in to an array in order to give it as an input to the autocomplete jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests are inherently *asynchronous*. That means you cannot return their value from a function. Instead you must provide a callback to then start working with the value:

```
function lookup ( inputString, callback ) {
    var responseArray = [];

    $.post("/airmanage/networkadmin/partnership_management/getMainDist.jsp",
        user: "" + inputString },
        function ( data ) {
            responseArray = data.split(",");
            callback(responseArray);
        });
}

lookup("a", function(arr) {
    alert(arr);
});
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, you can also use the Promise interface now available on AJAX requests:

```
function lookup ( inputString ) {
    var responseArray = [];

    return $.post("/airmanage/networkadmin/partnership_management/getMainDist.jsp", user: "" + inputString })
    .pipe(function( data ) {
        return data.split(',');
    });
}

lookup("a")
    .done(function(arr) {
        alert(arr);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the opening curly braces before `user`? And guess you should have a comma instaead of a plus before `inputString`.

Shouldn't this

```
$.post("/airmanage/networkadmin/partnership_management/getMainDist.jsp",user: ""+inputString+""},
```

be this -

```
$.post("/airmanage/networkadmin/partnership_management/getMainDist.jsp",{user: "", inputString:""},
```